# How do a create a responsive .SVG and use it as a mask?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a design I created that I am hoping to animated between two states (login -> dashboard).

## Before (Login)

[image]

## After (Dashboard)

[image]

When the user successful logs in, they will see:

- The bubbles reposition
- The red bubble move into the "Stove Temperature" card
- The header image form into the header bar
- The icon move to the header bar
- The sign in button disappear

This design will need to work on desktop and mobile.

## The Question

What is the best approach to make this header image transition into the header bar while maintaining responsive design?

### My Approach

I will use an SVG as a mask for the image. The image will be done with css as a background-image for a div tag. The SVG will mask this div tag. I will then animate the mask into a square to match the header when the user logs in.

### The Problem with the approach

I can't make an inline SVG be responsive in width while maintaining a consistent height (300px).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an SVG mask to achieve the image shape. You can do it with border radius.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

```js
document.getElementById("collapse").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("header").classList.toggle("collapsed");
});
```

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500/city/);
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 25% 25%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#header.collapsed {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>

<button id="collapse">Toggle</button>
```

If you don't like the shape of the radius at the left and right edges, then just make the `<div>` slightly wider than the screen so that they get trimmed off.

I can also show you how to do it with an SVG mask, but it is a lot less straightforward.

**With an SVG mask**

In this case we design a mask shape using a `<path>`. Then use two animation elements. One to collapse the mask shape by tweening the path to the flat rectangle shape, and another to tween it back out to its expanded shape.

To order to trigger those animations when we want, we set the `<animate>` `begin` times to `"indefinite"`. We can then set each animation running by calling the `beginElement()` method of each animation element.

```js
var expanded = true;

document.getElementById("collapse-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (expanded) {
    document.getElementById("collapse-anim").beginElement();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("expand-anim").beginElement();
  }
  expanded = !expanded;
});
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <svg width="100%" height="300px">
    <mask id="hdrmask" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M 0,0 L 1,0 L 1,0.75 C 0.75,1.08 0.25,1.08 0,0.75 Z" fill="white">
        <animate id="collapse-anim" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze"
                 to="M 0,0 L 1,0 L 1,0.25 C 0.67,0.25 0.33,0.25 0,0.25 Z" />
        <animate id="expand-anim" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze"
                 to="M 0,0 L 1,0 L 1,0.75 C 0.75,1.08 0.25,1.08 0,0.75 Z" />
      </path>
    </mask>
    
    <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/city/" width="100%" height="300px"
           preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" mask="url(#hdrmask)"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<button id="collapse-btn">Toggle</button>
```

To get the purple tint, all you need to do is put the image in a group with a transparent purple rectangle, and apply the mask to the group.

```js
var expanded = true;

document.getElementById("collapse-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (expanded) {
    document.getElementById("collapse-anim").beginElement();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("expand-anim").beginElement();
  }
  expanded = !expanded;
});
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <svg width="100%" height="300px">
    <mask id="hdrmask" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M 0,0 L 1,0 L 1,0.75 C 0.75,1.08 0.25,1.08 0,0.75 Z" fill="white">
        <animate id="collapse-anim" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze"
                 to="M 0,0 L 1,0 L 1,0.25 C 0.67,0.25 0.33,0.25 0,0.25 Z" />
        <animate id="expand-anim" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze"
                 to="M 0,0 L 1,0 L 1,0.75 C 0.75,1.08 0.25,1.08 0,0.75 Z" />
      </path>
    </mask>

    <g mask="url(#hdrmask)">
      <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/city/" width="100%" height="300px"
             preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="purple" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<button id="collapse-btn">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I conceptually knew it could be done with border-radius however I think this is a great time to learn SVG as eventually I'll hit a situation where I will be forced to do so. Could you demonstrate with SVG mask? I am doing lots of reading but the code won't work for me yet.